# Subversion and Windows Server 2008

Tags: svn, windows-server-2008

I install the [subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) on my windows server 2008. But it's only work localhost. It don't work when i try from another computer. I can't find out whats the problem is. Are there any ports or something like that i need to configure?

[This was the guide i follow](http://blogs.vertigosoftware.com/teamsystem/archive/2006/01/16/Setting_up_a_Subversion_Server_under_Windows.aspx)

Thaks for your help

Comment: did you try to use the computername? can you paste you SVN command and error?

Comment: yes, the can't find my host. but when i check the network the server can be find. 

The error with the computername: Unknown hostname 'forsmo01'

Comment: Can't connect to host '192.168.0.190': /// Error when i try the ip number

Comment: The ip number works fine when i try on the server. But not computername.

Comment: have you set it up under ssl?

Comment: Try with the server's IP address instead of the name. Odds are you need to add the server name and ip address to your hosts file.

Comment: I try the ip number, didn't work. No i don't use ssl. If i have it, should i need to use it with ssl when i run localhost?

Comment: Does your server have a firewall turned on? You need to explicitly allow traffic to port 3690.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. The port!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's add the solution as an answer, too. When you run the standalone svnserve server, you need to set up your firewall to allow traffic to port 3690 on the host machine.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried using this - we are using it - free and easy to setup.

http://www.visualsvn.com/server/

Josh

Comment: Won't help much, as his issue seems to be related to resolving the host name of the server.

Comment: why should i try that if it work localhost but not from another computer? It's just in the configuration i think...

Comment: if its a setup issue then this is a much simpler solution that i've setup without any issues - just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem.
Make sure that svnserve uses IP V4 instead of IP V6. You can do this by adding the parameter 
   **--listen-host 0.0.0.0** 
to the commandline of svnserve.

Answer (score 0):

Go to a free DNS service such as DynDNS or no-ip.com and register a free domain, such as fluffybunnytail.dyndns.org.  You must then download an IP-update client (both DynDNS and No-IP have their own clients).  The client will then keep your IP updated on the DNS server whenever it changes.  This way you can always access the SVN server via the domain name you registered (e.g. fluffybunnytail.dyndnds.org).